# How to send value from one page to another in html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

[enter image description here]I want to display data here

Please help.

```
$(function() {
  var RETAIL_CRM = [];
var dmJSON = "https://cordova.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/CRM.jsp";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
   $.each(data.RETAIL_CRM, function(i, f) {

         var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=Details.html?value="+f.S_NO+"&value1="+f.STATUS+"&value2="+f.NAME+">" + f.S_NO +"</td>" + "</a>" + "<td>"+ f.NAME+ "</td>"+ "<td>" + f.STATUS + "</td>" + "</tr>";     
                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#list");


 });

        document.getElementById("crm_serialnumber").value = value;
        document.getElementById("crm_name").value = value1;
        document.getElementById("crm_status").value = value2;


});
});
```

home.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

here am printing json vale SR_NO NAME and Status and using href tag on S.NO

Suppose I click on K.M.P Medicals then it should goes to next page (Details.html)

(attached img2) and print the same SNO, Name ,and Status on this page.

[image: image1]

Details.html (second page) I wasnt o print my values here .

Thanks

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

**You can send value one page to another using query string**

please refer this code

```
  // Convert query string into Single Search Paramerter
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    
    // To get the parameter 
    var userid = getParameterByName("UserId");

    // To send parameter to another page
    window.location.href="xyz.html?UserId="+parameter ;
```